# How to reduce the height of MatInput and Matselect

Tags: angular-material

I am using this type of [Material](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples) input but I need to reduce the height a little.
It seems not easy to do especially when the input is a mat-select and something is selected.
Is there a way to do it without rewriting all the component/CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `::ng-deep` to override css properties of angular material components.

eg =>  `::ng-deep .mat-input-element { height: 30px; }`

hope this answers your question.
for more information on ::ng-deep [follow the link](https://ngrefs.com/styling/ng-deep-selector)

Comment: ok, but I need to personalize only 1 input, and also if I attach my custom CSS class I can't personalize all the component